# DomainClassConverter double conversion

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I am trying to use Spring's DomainClassConverter feature with my Spring MVC project. But I got a problem with my controllers.
The problem is that I can not get the changed values of the form  to ModelAttribute.
For example: I have object `User{id: 1, username: "user", pass: "111"}` in my database, when I try to modify it into form end post changes (`User{id: 1, username: "user_changed", pass: "222"})` to controller, I receive the persistent User(without changes)

`@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView create(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user,
                               BindingResult bindingResultUser,
                               ModelAndView model,
                               WebRequest webRequest,
                               Locale locale) {...}`

After some time spent debugging,  I find the reason of such converter behavior.

first starts from this row when ModelAttributeMethodProcessor try to convert bound user object to ModelAttribute: **return binder.convertIfNecessary(binder.getTarget(), parameter.getParameterType(), parameter);**

```
@Override
public final Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
        NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

    String name = ModelFactory.getNameForParameter(parameter);
    Object attribute = (mavContainer.containsAttribute(name) ?
            mavContainer.getModel().get(name) : createAttribute(name, parameter, binderFactory, webRequest));

    WebDataBinder binder = binderFactory.createBinder(webRequest, attribute, name);
    if (binder.getTarget() != null) {
        bindRequestParameters(binder, webRequest);
        validateIfApplicable(binder, parameter);
        if (binder.getBindingResult().hasErrors() && isBindExceptionRequired(binder, parameter)) {
            throw new BindException(binder.getBindingResult());
        }
    }

    // Add resolved attribute and BindingResult at the end of the model
    Map<String, Object> bindingResultModel = binder.getBindingResult().getModel();
    mavContainer.removeAttributes(bindingResultModel);
    mavContainer.addAllAttributes(bindingResultModel);

    return binder.convertIfNecessary(binder.getTarget(), parameter.getParameterType(), parameter);
}
```

Then, DataBinder-> invoke the ConversionService->DomainClassConverter to convert User object to convert it into ModelAttribute.
DomainConverter first converts User->Id, then back in User, at this moment User is re-reading from the database and lost all modified assignments that DataBinder made.

I solve this problem when i replaced this row ~~if (sourceType.equals(targetType)) {~~ to **if (sourceType.getType() != null && sourceType.getType().equals(targetType.getType())) {**

```
    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {

        if (source == null || !StringUtils.hasText(source.toString())) {
            return null;
        }

        if (sourceType.equals(targetType)) {
            return source;
        }

        Class<?> domainType = sourceType.getType();

        EntityInformation<Object, ?> entityInformation = repositories.getEntityInformationFor(domainType);

        return conversionService.convert(entityInformation.getId(source), targetType.getType());
    }
```

in theory we have to compare types but TypeDescriptors. Or I was wrong?